# Rails Generate command error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails version 4.2.7.1 and ruby 2.2.5 with rvm.
After bundle update I cannot run `rails g` command anymore.
The following error keeps appearing:

```
-- [](4.2)
/Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:664:in `block in method_missing': undefined method `[]' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x007fce8f996460> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:288:in `measure'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:416:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/encrypted_store-0.3.0/lib/generators/encrypted_store/upgrade/ZeroOneFive/templates/upgrade_encryption_keys_to_015.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/encrypted_store-0.3.0/lib/encrypted_store/railtie.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/encrypted_store-0.3.0/lib/encrypted_store/railtie.rb:18:in `each'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/encrypted_store-0.3.0/lib/encrypted_store/railtie.rb:18:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:228:in `call'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:228:in `block in run_generators_blocks'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:245:in `each'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:245:in `each_registered_block'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:228:in `run_generators_blocks'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:462:in `block in run_generators_blocks'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:462:in `run_generators_blocks'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:461:in `load_generators'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:129:in `generate_or_destroy'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Already tried reinstalling gemset and deleting all previous migration files, but it did not help. What could be the reason?

Comment: Did you run rails db:migrate command?

Comment: How do you run it? Do you use `bin/rails`?

Comment: When are you facing this error? Is there any migration pending?

Comment: I use just ‘rails g’, there are no pending migrations

Comment: Why did this ‘ - - [] (4.2)’ start appearing after I enter command?

Comment: I think some dependencies are messed up. Do you use git? You can check what was updated and make a rollback

Comment: Use `bin/rails g` then.

Comment: Have you tried `bundle exec rails g ...`

Comment: I have tried `bundle exec` and `bin/rails`. It is all the same. I do not use git for development. I even reinstalled gemset, it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I solved by myself. As I could see from this line

```
from /Users/Sergei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@rails4/gems/encrypted_store-0.3.0/lib/generators/encrypted_store/upgrade/ZeroOneFive/templates/upgrade_encryption_keys_to_015.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

It had dependency from gem encrypted_store. I removed this gem from Gemfile and reinstalled in with bundle command (gem 'encrypted_store', '~> 0.2.8'). After this the error was gone.